# Hybrid AngularJS/Angular 6 app module dependency issues

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

I'm currently exploring an upgrade path for a pretty large AngularJS 1.6 app to Angular 6.  I have my app bootstrapping as a hybrid app, and I've begun converting individual modules and components. I need to be able to do the migration in chunks, though. It would be nice if I could migrate a module at a time, but I'm running into some issues, to that end.

I have a `NavBar` directive which resides in my `core` AngularJS module. That component is being downgraded with `downgradeComponent` and registered on the AngularJS `core` module. The `landing` AngularJS module has a dependency on the `core` module so that it can use the `NavBar`. This works fine, because the `LandingComponent` has also been converted to Angular6 and is being downgraded and registered on the `landing` AngularJS module.

There is a problem with using the `NavBar` component inside of any other AngularJS component, though. I have a third AngularJS module called `workflows` with a `ViewWorkflows` component that has a `NavBar` inside its template. When I navigate to that component, I get the following error:

`angular.js:14791 Error: No component factory found for NavBarDirective. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`

I can fix this by converting and then downgrading `ViewWorkflows`, but since `NavBar` is being registered as a downgraded AngularJS component, shouldn't any AngularJS module that declares a dependency on the `core` module have access to it?

[Code (Not runnable)](https://gist.github.com/jacob-robertson/bcafbeaaf20e0b169f07c661a56bcd6b)

Edit: I've updated the gist to be a little more simple. The `landing` module is Angular, with an Angular component, `<landing>` that is downgraded to run on the AngularJS `landing` module and has a `<t-nav-bar>` inside it. It has a dependency on the `core` module which provides the downgraded `<t-nav-bar>` directive. The `<test>` component is an AngularJS component registered on the AngularJS `landing` module that cannot use the `<t-nav-bar>`. Without even bringing the `workflows` module into the situation, it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you have any code to show how you've downgraded the Angular component and how you're registering it with AngularJs?

Comment: also, I believe, every downgraded component has to be declared in an Angular module as an entry component in @NgModule

Comment: I can wrangle something together. I'm not saying you're wrong about it needing to be an entry component, but I _can_ get it working without that, and adding it doesn't fix the problem. The working solution is that every component that uses the downgraded directive must also be a downgraded component/directive. That's a much less tenable upgrade path in such a large, modular application.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#using-angular-components-from-angularjs-code

scroll down just a bit and it has the stipulation in the docs

Comment: I appreciate the thought, but I've combed through that article several times. It does not address my use case, and as far as I can tell, I'm not violating any of the rules laid out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to sort this out. I was trying to declare the `NavBar` as an Angular `@Directive`. It actually needs to be a `@Component`. After making that switch, it works exactly as expected.

I spun up [this](https://github.com/jacob-robertson/angular-hybrid) repo to test with, and discovered the issue there. It's a new Angular 6 app that I "downgraded" for experimenting.